# cannot import name patterns with Django1.6

Tags: python, django

Python v2; Django v1.6

when I start server, I got the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

Code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

 urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment', app_name='payment')),
)
```

Next:
I've also tried to change import code like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```

but gotanother error:

```
NameError: name 'patterns' is not defined
```

Comment: no matter what, upgrade your django to 1.11 or higher.

Comment: If that import isn't working, then it looks like you aren't using Django 1.6. Try `import django; print(django.VERSION)` to check which version you are running. Note that Django 1.6 is very out-of-date and insecure. You should upgrade to Python 3 and the latest 2.2.X release. If you are stuck on Python 2, at least try to upgrade to the latest 1.11.X LTS which supported until April 2020.

Comment: it is an old server; i can not upgrade django's version

Comment: @Alasdair, version is ok; i installed it just now;
    
    print(django.VERSION)    (1, 6, 0, 'final', 0)

Comment: Harsh, but: then you shouldn't develop a new Django application on that server.

Comment: yeah, but i'm checking a bug; so i want to start it on my pc , but i failed

Comment: Then either there's something wrong with your install, or when you run `print(django.VERSION)` you are using a different version of Django than the one that is giving the import error. Django 1.6 shouldn't give that import error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another version of Django (something like Django 1.3.X?) in your PYTHONPATH? Try using a virtualenv with Django 1.6(.11 if you can)

Comment: i start it in a virtual env with my pyCharm